# ¡Como cambio el color de un botón cuando lo selecciono y desmarco si selecciono otro en un formulario?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

tengo un problema, estoy haciendo un cuestionario, quiero que los botones del cuestionario solo se pueda seleccionar una opción y que cada opción se marque de un color distinto, es decir, que si selecciono el primer botón quede de color azul, y si marco la segunda opción de la misma pregunta se desmarque el primer botón y el segundo quede azul, a día de hoy no he podido hacerlo por medio de javascript, si alguien me puede ayudar.
les dejo mi codigo: https://codepen.io/TrueAFM/pen/vYJZKjq

Comment: El código debe ir _en la pregunta_, no como enlace externo. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Además, escribe un título más descriptivo: por ejemplo, cuál es el problema que estás teniendo.

Comment: Creo que deberías usar inputs de tipo radio https://codepen.io/jaimemenendez/pen/zYdzKYM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema en tu código es que estas usando checkboxes en vez de radiobuttons. Los radiobuttons al seleccionar uno, siempre que tengan el mismo nombre, cambiara el seleccionado. Te adjunto un ejemplo de w3schools que es bastante claro, solo tendrías que cambiar tu código
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_radio
Suerte!

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer es esto utilizando puro css en HTML5:

```
CODIGO DE HTML        
<section class="estilos"><h1>Discos Duros</h1></section>
<section class="estilos"><h1>Teclados</h1></section>
<section class="estilos"><h1>Fuentes de poder</h1></section>
<section class="estilos"><h1>Mouses</h1></section>
<section class="estilos"><h1>Procesadores</h1></section>
<section class="estilos"><h1>Quemadores</h1></section>
<section class="estilos"><h1>Tarjetas de video</h1></section>
<section class="estilos"><h1>teclados</h1></section>
<section class="estilos"><h1>ventiladores</h1></section>   

CODIGO EN CSS
.estilos:hover{
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #1A2A40;
color: #fff;
transition:0.4s ease-in-out 0.1s;}
```

para así darle un cambio de color a tus botones y una trancicion

Comment: No entiendo como funciona. No lo explicas. Tampoco dices que hay que cambiar en el código del OP.